# How do I use .NET Maui to convert a server side Blazor webstie to an Android app?

Tags: android, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, maui

I've been reading up on .NET Maui and I want to create an app with my existing server side Blazor app. We are already running .NET 6 on the website. I downloaded Android Studio but I am not sure what my next steps are. Can anyone point me to a tutorial or documentation showing how to create the Android app from my existing server side Blazor website?

Comment: As far as I'll know you'll need to use the .NET Maui template for this.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Android Studio? No, you need Visual Studio 2022.
- See [Blazor Hybrid apps with .NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#blazor-hybrid-apps-with-net-maui). Has links to tutorials, walkthrough.
- As Marvin mentions, you will use .Net Maui template.
- Your Blazor/Razor components will be displayed in a Maui `BlazorWebView` .
- Server code that is not part of a component will not port over; Maui docs describe app initialization.
- Google `site:stackoverflow.com maui blazor` to see various issues, and how people resolved them.
- Don't add questions as comments to this answer. Search for previous Q&As. If you don't find an appropriate one, create a new SO question, for each Blazor question.